# Is there some place to put custom functions which are then sourced at startup?

Tags: bash, bashrc

I've written a what I think quite useful function and I want to make it public via GitHub. On my PC I have a `.bash_functions` file which I source into my `.bashrc` file. I know this is the common approach (at least for bash) but I don't know if it is very userfriendly to expect from my users to put the function in there manually.

So, my question is, is there maybe some unified global place (somewhere in `etc` maybe) where I can put my custom functions which get then sourced at startup? So that when the user want's to install this function he just needs to type `make` and it will be placed into this folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think It's good idea to use .bashrc but if you want a global way then you can put your file with functions in this place

`/etc/profile.d/your_file_with_functions.sh`

Also you can use other way

`/etc/bash.bashrc`

and put there

`[ -r /path/to/your/file   ] && . /path/to/your/file`